# How to exclude hidden row vaue from total value SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have an SSRS project and I want to exclude a row that I have hidden from the total.

I have hidden the row based on an expression on the row visibility, where the row is hidden if:

```
=IIF(IIF(ReportItems!CUST_CNT2.Value = 0, 0, ReportItems!Total_Contribution5.Value / IIF(ReportItems!CUST_CNT2.Value = 0, 1, ReportItems!CUST_CNT2.Value)) > 0, True, False)
```

So basically the column totals for the report just total up all rows including this above row that I have hidden, and I need the total to exclude this row.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to filter this data out earlier: by defining a tablix filter, a dataset filter, or changing the query. Then you don't need to do anything more. Do you really need the row in your data for some other reason?

But you can also use your expression, with a little twist, inside an aggregate. Set the total to be:

```
=SUM( IIF( IIF(ReportItems!CUST_CNT2.Value = 0, 
               0,
               ReportItems!Total_Contribution5.Value /
                 IIF(ReportItems!CUST_CNT2.Value = 0,
                     1,
                     ReportItems!CUST_CNT2.Value)
              ) > 0,
           0,
           ReportItems!Total_Contribution5.Value) )
```

The change to your expression is that now a hidden row returns 0 while a visible row returns the field to be totaled. (I took a guess at what you want totaled. Change the field as needed.) This is all wrapped up in the aggregate `SUM(...)`